# Dynamically changing route animations using react-router

Tags: react-router

I'm trying to make a `react-router` app that animates page transitions using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, but I can't figure out how to dynamically set `transitionName` so that I can use different animations depending on the route I am trying to go to. For example, I want root routes to fade between each other, but children routes should slide in/out - aka, I want it to work like a native app.

When using the code:

```
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName={transitionValue}
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
    >
    ...
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

How can I make `transitionValue` something that can either be set by a `Link` component or based on the route that is loaded? I'm not sure the best way to do this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best option, but I added `query` to the Link and then accessed it via `this.props.location.query.tran`

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName={this.props.location.query.tran || 'fade'}
  transitionEnterTimeout={500}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
>
...
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

And the link looks like this:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/role/1', query: { tran: 'coverLeft' }}}/>
```

Hope this helps someone. Or, if anyone has a better approach, I'd love to hear it as I don't love that my solution dirties the URL a bit.